# Can you set a variable in the node editor to check if a light source is hitting a normal?

Tags: materials, node-editor

Can you set a variable in the node editor to check if a light source is hitting a normal and then take the information of which normal are being hit and which ones aren't to change the material?

For example, I have a glass shader, and a diffuse shader. If there is no light  hitting the object it will just be diffuse if light is touching the normal it will turn into a glass shader.

Im trying to see if I can get shadows from a texture by making a shadeless material and having a shadow layer and a lit layer that will mask itself on top of the shadow when light is hitting it this way I can get hand painted shadows.